# Trouble Saving Settings to JSON File with tauri-settings in a Vue/Tauri Application

Tags: json, vuejs3, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, tauri

Hello and a happy new year (in advance :) ),

I am working on a desktop application using Nuxt3 and Tauri, and I am encountering an issue with saving settings to a JSON file using the `[tauri-settings from harshkhandeparkar](https://github.com/harshkhandeparkar/tauri-settings)` library.

I am relatively new to coding and use this to learn nuxt3 (for another web developement project) and rust, cause I did not want to use electron :D and python (which I used before). I is not about being the most efficient and I am doing this solely for hobby use. I am no where near professional developement.

I tried following the library documentation and implementing the recommended methods, but the settings are not being saved to the `settings.json` file.

I added the requested permissions in the `tauri.conf.json`

I do not get any errors in console (or atleast I think so) so I have no idea where to search for my mistake.

I use a hook to manage my settings in my settings.vue

In the docs it is said, that you need to set the settings to the `cache` (`updateSetting` function) and write it with `syncCache` (`saveSettingsToDisk` function) to the `settings.json`. At least I hope I did this.
I've added console logs to trace the flow and it seems the `saveSettingsToDisk` function gets called correctly, but the file still doesn't update. (1st Log is showing) but I think `await settingsManager.syncCache();` is not called and the log after that is not responding.

**useSettings.ts (Custom Hook):**

```
// useSettings.ts
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { SettingsManager } from 'tauri-settings';

interface Settings {
  sourceDirectory: string;
  targetDirectory: string;
  selectedCopyMode: string | null;
  selectedLanguage: string | null;
}

const settingsManager = new SettingsManager('copybot-settings');
const settings = ref<Settings>({
  sourceDirectory: '',
  targetDirectory: '',
  selectedCopyMode: null,
  selectedLanguage: null,
});

const copyModes = ref(['Auto', 'Manual']);
const languages = ref(['English', 'Deutsch', 'Français']);

export const useSettings = () => {
  const loadSettings = async () => {
    try {
      const loadedSettings = await settingsManager.get('settings');
      if (loadedSettings) {
        settings.value = loadedSettings;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to load settings:", error);
    }
  };

  const updateSetting = async (key, value) => {
    settingsManager.setCache(key, value);
  };

  const saveSettings = async () => {
    try {
      await settingsManager.set('settings', settings.value);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to save settings:", error);
    }
  };

  const saveSettingsToDisk = async () => {
    try {
      console.log("Saving the settings:", settings.value);
      await settingsManager.syncCache();
      console.log("Settings saved.");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Failed to save settings on disk:", error);
      if (error instanceof Error) {
        console.error("Error Details:", error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  watch(settings, saveSettings, { deep: true });

  return {
    settings,
    loadSettings,
    saveSettings,
    copyModes,
    languages,
    saveSettingsToDisk,
    updateSetting  
  };
};
```

**The settings.vue:**

```js
<template>
  <v-container>
    <!-- Kopfzeile -->
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <!-- Source Directory -->
    <v-row align="center">
      <v-col cols="10">
        <v-text-field
          label="Source Directory"
          v-model="settings.sourceDirectory"
          readonly
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="2">
        <v-btn @click="browseDirectory">Browse</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <!-- Copy Mode -->
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-select
          label="Copy Mode"
          :items="copyModes"
          :value="settings.selectedCopyMode"
          @input="(value) => updateSetting('selectedCopyMode', value)"
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <!-- Language Selection -->
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12">
        <v-select
          label="Language"
          :items="languages"
          v-model="settings.selectedLanguage"
        ></v-select>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>

    <!-- Target Directory -->
    <v-row align="center">
      <v-col cols="10">
        <v-text-field
          label="Target Directory"
          v-model="settings.targetDirectory"
          readonly
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols="2">
        <v-btn @click="setTargetDirectory">Set Target</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>

  <v-row>
    <v-col>
      <v-btn @click="saveSettingsToDisk">Einstellungen speichern</v-btn>
    </v-col>
  </v-row>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import { useSettings } from "../hooks/useSettings";

const {
  settings,
  loadSettings,
  copyModes,
  languages,
  saveSettingsToDisk,
  updateSetting
} = useSettings();

const browseDirectory = () => {
  /* ... */
};
const setTargetDirectory = () => {
  /* ... */
};

onMounted(loadSettings);
</script>
```

**tauri.conf.json:** (snippet)

```json
  "tauri": {
    "allowlist": {
      "all": false,
      "fs": {
        "createDir": true,
        "removeDir": true,
        "readDir": true,
        "copyFile": true,
        "readFile": true,
        "writeFile": true,
        "removeFile": true,
        "renameFile": true,
        "exists": true,
        "scope": ["$APPCONFIG", "$APPCONFIG/*"]
      },
      "path": {
        "all": true
```

Am I missing something in my implementation? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!